# C++ ffmpeg encoded audio is distorted

Tags: c++, audio, ffmpeg

I've made a demuxer/muxer program that takes a video as an input, takes audio and video, then just encodes that red information. So far the video is working fine but the audio is faulty. I can hear the original audio of the input in the background but there is a distorted static sound on the front. I'm setting the `AVFrame` I got from the demuxer and some information about `AVCodecContext` in the encoder. The rest is some what similar to ffmpegs muxing example

Here is what I've done so far:

```cpp
int video_encoder::write_audio_frame(AVFormatContext *oc, OutputStream *ost)
{
    AVCodecContext *c;
    AVFrame *frame;
    int ret;
    int dst_nb_samples;

    c = ost->enc;

#if __AUDIO_ENABLED
    c->bit_rate = input_sample_fmt.bit_rate;
    c->sample_rate = input_sample_fmt.sample_rate;
    c->time_base = input_sample_fmt.time_base;
    c->sample_fmt =  input_sample_fmt.sample_fmt;
    c->channel_layout =  input_sample_fmt.channel_layout;
    //c-> =  input_sample_fmt.channel_layout
#endif

    frame = get_audio_frame(ost);

    if (frame) {
        /* convert samples from native format to destination codec format, using the resampler */
        /* compute destination number of samples */
        dst_nb_samples = av_rescale_rnd(swr_get_delay(ost->swr_ctx, c->sample_rate) + frame->nb_samples,
                                        c->sample_rate, c->sample_rate, AV_ROUND_UP);
        //av_assert0(dst_nb_samples == frame->nb_samples);

        /* when we pass a frame to the encoder, it may keep a reference to it
         * internally;
         * make sure we do not overwrite it here
         */
        ret = av_frame_make_writable(ost->frame);
        if (ret < 0)
            exit(1);

        /* convert to destination format */
        ret = swr_convert(ost->swr_ctx,
                          ost->frame->data, dst_nb_samples,
                          (const uint8_t **)frame->data, frame->nb_samples);
        if (ret < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error while converting\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        frame = ost->frame;

        frame->pts = av_rescale_q(ost->samples_count, (AVRational){1, c->sample_rate}, c->time_base);
        ost->samples_count += dst_nb_samples;
    }


    return write_frame(oc, c, ost->st, frame, ost->tmp_pkt);
}


void video_encoder::set_audio_frame(AVFrame* audio, AVCodecContext* c_ctx)
{
    audio_data = *audio;
    input_sample_fmt = *c_ctx;
    //std::cout << audio-> << std::endl;
}

AVFrame* video_encoder::get_audio_frame(OutputStream *ost)
{
    AVFrame *frame = &audio_data;
    int j, i, v;
    int16_t *q = (int16_t*)frame->data[0];


    //(int16_t)*audio_frame->data[0];
    /* check if we want to generate more frames */
    if (av_compare_ts(ost->next_pts, ost->enc->time_base,
                      STREAM_DURATION, (AVRational){ 1, 1 }) > 0)
        return NULL;

    for (j = 0; j <frame->nb_samples; j++) {
        #if !__AUDIO_ENABLED
            v = (int)(sin(ost->t) * 10000);
        #endif
        for (i = 0; i < ost->enc->channels; i++)
        #if !__AUDIO_ENABLED
            *q++ = v;
        #endif
        ost->t     += ost->tincr;
        ost->tincr += ost->tincr2;
    }

    frame->pts = ost->next_pts;
    ost->next_pts  += frame->nb_samples;

#if __AUDIO_ENABLED        
    return frame;
#else
    return frame;
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should match input and output sample rates.

Your output buffer is allocated regarding your output audio specifications.

However, as they are different than your input audio specifications; either it is underflowing and unable to fill your buffer in a input compatible way, or overflowing.

The latter one is unlikely, as you mentioned that you hear the audio but in a distorted way.